# C# Trying to create a global object instance with optional parameters from inside of a method

Tags: c#, object, methods, global-variables

So I'm pretty new to object-oriented programming (EE with electromagnetics and circuits by trade) and I might be thinking of this completely wrong. My goal is to create around 15-20 objects that have x number of properties each, two of those properties are required and one is optional with a "false" string default. This is all based on parsed input from a text file. I need these objects accessible (without returning because I have another boolean parameter to return to the parent method. Here is what my object class looks like (inside of my main class)

```
public class Variable
{
    public string varName { get; set;}
    public string varVal { get; set;}
    public string varParam {get; set;} //My optional parameter

    public Variable (string varName1, string varVal1, string, varParam1 = "false")
    {
        varName = varName1;
        varVal = varVal1;
        varParam = varParam1;
    }
}
```

Now, in my main code, I have a method that gets a string passed to it (a line in a text file). I tried putting together multiple things I read online about global variables :

```
public bool Method1 (string textLine, int lineIndex)
{
    string parsedText = ...;
    string parsedValue = ...;

    ...

    public static Variable var1 = new Variable( parsedText, parsedValue);
    return false;
}
```

So essentially I need:

**Parent class -> program main -> Method1 -> create object1 (with optional params) -> return boolean -> program main -> Method2 -> access object1**

Currently it doesn't work because the method variable creation line returns errors so it won't compile. I'm sure I'm doing it wrong, but I couldn't find anything that combined globally accessed objects created within a method (only created within a class). I can't make the class static because I can't have an instance method within a static class.

Any help would be extremely appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [jason.kaisersmith's thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61722669/9259080) I was able to see that what I was looking for was a static object List (since I would be accessing objects (different classes making total number of objects in the 50s or so with the 6 or 7 different object Lists) from multiple methods in the program class, here is what I added to my program class and replaced for the method (bool is due to some other error logic I built in):

```
public static List<Variable> variableList = new List<Variable>();

...

public bool Method1 (string textLine, int lineIndex)
{
    string parsedText = ...;
    string parsedValue = ...;

    ...

    variableList.Add(new Variable( parsedText, parsedValue));
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I have understood you correctly then you want your method to return true or false to indicate that processing was successful or not AND your method should return a created instance (I assume only if successful).

You can consider changing the concept of how you approach this.  Then there are a few ways you can do this and you will need to select which one suits your program best.  Maybe the last way is best for you in this case?

**1:  Return null**

If processing is successful, then you return a valid object.  If not, then you return null.
Your calling process then checks if it received null or not.  If so, then it knows processing failed.

```
Variable var = Method1(...);
if (var != null)
{
 ....
}
```

**2:  Throw exception**

Similar to option 1.  But if processing fails, you throw an exception.
Your calling process must capture this and then handle it.

```
try
{
    Variable var = Method1(...);
    ....
} catch(Exception ex)
{
  //handle exception

}
```

**3:  Expand your class**

You could expand the class of the object you want to return to include the boolean operator.  (I don't like this so much!)

**4:  Out parameter**

In your method you define that one parameter is an out parameter.  This allows it to be passed into your method and out again.
This probably does not suit your use case, as you don't need to pass it in & out.

```
Variable var = new Variable();
retValue = Method1(out var, ....);
```

**5:  return a Tuple**

You can actually return multiple values from a method as a Tuple.  So you can return your boolean and your new object.
Code example:

```
//Define your method signature to return two elements
public (bool, Variable ) Method1 (string textLine, int lineIndex)
{
    Variable var = new Variable();
    ...
    //Return your elements
    return (false, var);
}

//Call method like this
(bool retvalue, Variable retVar) = Method1(....);
if (retValue)
{
 ....
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the ideas! Since I am dynamically adding a text file, my biggest issue is being able to create in instance of the object from within the message (as I won't know the number of objects specified in the text file), and be able to use them globally. Option 5 might be close to that, but would I then have to pass all 15-20 objects (and I will be doing multiple object classes, so in reality, 100 objects or so of different types) between methods with every call?

Comment: @Ben Then simply put them in a List.  If this doesn't work, then you have the wrong design for your program!

Comment: Ah! I really think that was what I was looking for! Would it make more sense design-wise to pass 3-4 object lists and return lists, or to make them static? I assume I could dynamically ".add()" to a static list?

Comment: @Ben  Passing your objects is normally the best approach, as you don't copy the data anyway so it is very efficient.  You can also store in a static class, or Singleton (or do both!), it really depends.   If you don't need access to the data at any other time, then passing is definitely better.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare required static variables globally and initialize inside the method as per text files.
class Program
    {

```
    public static Variable var1;

    public bool Method1(string textLine, int lineIndex)
    {
        string parsedText = "122";
        string parsedValue = "123";


        var1 = new Variable(parsedText, parsedValue);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: so, would this mean that I would have to declare all of my objects initially? I am reading lines from a text file and creating objects based on that, so I can't hardcode number of objects.